# How to copy Japanese encoded text (other than Unicode type) to clipboard using java?

Tags: java, encoding, clipboard

So, I've made a program that successfully catch text from clipboard and print it via System.out.println in Java. Then, I want to copy the modified text to clipboard. Here is a snippet of that code:

```
                 StringSelection ss = new StringSelection(result);                        
                 Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss, null);
```

Result is the modified String, and when I print result variable to console, it's still readable.But, the copied text on the clipboard seems to have different encoding from the original one, and it displays unreadable characters instead.

Is there anything that I can do to overcome that problem? Any answer is greatly appreciated, thank you :)

EDITED:
Sorry, it turns out that the text is readable just fine when copied to any windows programs such as sticky note, word, etc. But when I copied it to Atlas Translator, it seems that it can't read Unicode encoding stream which I suspect the default encoding in java.

So, my revised question is: how can I convert the stringselection such that it has japanese encoding, but not in Unicode? Any answer is greatly appreciated, thanks! :)

Comment: I tested your code on Simplified Chinese Windows XP system (GBK/CP936 encoding), it works as expected. Maybe you can print the byte array result of `result` to see the raw data in it.

Comment: Works for me, Japanese or Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

Try this program, will solve your problem

```
public class UTFDemo {

    public static void main(String s[]) {
        //String message = "Езикова";
        String message = "LiuYan 刘研";
        System.out.println("Original Message : " + message);
        StringSelection ss = new StringSelection(message);
        Clipboard cb = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        cb.setContents(ss, null);

        String result = getClipboardContents();
        System.out.println("Result : " + result);
    }

    public static String getClipboardContents() {
        String result = "";
        Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        //odd: the Object param of getContents is not currently used
        Transferable contents = clipboard.getContents(null);
        boolean hasTransferableText =
                (contents != null)
                && contents.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
        if (hasTransferableText) {
            try {
                result = (String) contents.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
            } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException ex) {
                //highly unlikely since we are using a standard DataFlavor
                System.out.println(ex);
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: actually Rahul, when I use your code, the result is the same as mine.

Comment: Rahul, the result of the code is the same as mine. The copied clipboard from Java is readable when pasted on any programs except on Fujitsu Atlas translator. The strange thing is, when I run the program, pasted the text to sticky note, and re-copied it again with ctrl+c, Atlas can read the text just fine now. So, I think the problem is the encoding that Java used when copying that Japanese text, and the one that Windows used when copying manually with ctrl+c. Do you have any idea to set the encoding that java used to be the exact same with the one that Windows used when copying a text? :)